# Get dummy variables in Pandas where rows contain multiple variables as a list?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, dummy-variable

Consider a Pandas dataframe which has a column 'id', and the rows of this column consists of list of strings representing categories. What is an efficient way to obtain the dummy variables?

Example:

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['0,1', '24,25', '1,24']})
```

Output:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'0':[1, 0, 0],
               '1': [1, 0, 1],
               '24':[0, 1, 1],
               '25':[0, 1, 0]})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `.str` accessor version of [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df1['id'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

The resulting output:

```
   0  1  24  25
0  1  1   0   0
1  0  0   1   1
2  0  1   1   0
```